# I want to add a class to main div on a template. how can I do that?

Tags: theme-twenty-ten, child-theme

I'm building a template for twentyten child theme. I need to add a class in  in the template page, but not in other pages.My template inherits the header and footer, so, I can't change any markup there. How can I add a class in there without adding that class to other pages? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: twenty ten uses body_class - so each page has already a unique css class. what are you trying to achieve that would require a specific css class?

Comment: I'm actually trying to add top margin. and my template isn't echoing any class, just <div id="main">. It inherits everything from it's parent theme except the sidebar, which is different.

Comment: the page specific class is added to the body tag; for special styling, use something like this in style.css  `.page-template-yourtemplatename-php #main { ... }`

Comment: sorry, I wanted to mark your comment as great, but I can't find the arrow on the side as stackoverflow has!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
<?php

    function add_classes_to_body_class($classes) {

            // make sure 'page-template.php' matches your template name
            if ( is_page_template('page-template.php') ) {
                $classes[] = 'main';
            }
        return $classes;
    }
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_classes_to_body_class' );

?>
```

make sure you add `body_class()` into your markup. Traditionally it would be in your body tag like so. `<body id="foobar" <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Comment: @Snowbell92 no problem, glad to help out.